# Shortest point on a line segment from point outside the line

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

[image]

From the above pic I found the value $x$ from line $(p1,p2)$ and point a using $y=mx+b$ and imaginary red line which is perpendicular to black line having  slope $-1/m$ and the intersecting point $x$.

The problem is that $x$ is not actual intersecting point

See pic below :

[image]

Comment: Keep in mind that GoogleEarth perhaps does not plot your points correctly and second, that those points are not points on a plane but rather on a 'sphere like' object.

Comment: the problem is on Google map not in Google earth. I think the problem is caused by the numbers having long precisions

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Admitting the exitence of a solution along the normal, suppose that the coordinates of point$p_1$ are ($x_1,y_1)$ and that the coordinates of point $p_2$ are ($x_2,y_2)$, the equation of the black line is given by $y=a + b x$ with $b=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$ and $a=y_1-b x_1$.

The point outside the line has coordinates ($x_0,y_0$). The slope of the red line is $-\frac{1}{b}$ so the equation of the line being $y=c-\frac{1}{b}x$ and this line goes through the point ${x_0,y_0}$. So $$y_0=c-\frac{1}{b}x_0$$ gives $c=y_0+\frac{1}{b}x_0$.

So, now, you look for the intersection of $y=a+b x$ and $y=c-\frac{1}{b}x$. So $$a+b x=c-\frac{1}{b}x$$ Solve for $x$ and compute $y$ by one of the two equations.

I am sure that you can take from here (use letters and not numbers till the end)